# cloudflare ssl for staging subdomain: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, amazon-eks

I have the following setup
cloudflare -> aws nlb -> ingress nginx controller (aws eks) -> kubernetes service -> kubernetes pod.

Cloudflare has edge certificates enabled for
*.project.com, project.com and are installed in ingress-nginx as

Cloudflare has origin server ssl cert for
*.staging.project.com, *.project.com, project.com (3 hosts) that I installed inside kubernetes cluster.

```
extraArgs:
  default-ssl-certificate: ingress-nginx/cloudflare-origin-cert
```

However I'm unable to connect to argocd.staging.project.com  via HTTPs due to handshake error. It should work as origin server cert has *.project.com and also *.staging.project.com.

Inside cloudflare I have just a single domain "project.com", as it seems cloudflare does not allow me to have a staging hosted zone.

#### What am I missing or doing wrong?

prod env works just fine with this setup, but not staging. I can change argocd.staging.project.com > /argocd-staging.project.com and everything would work, but I prefer to keep staging subdomain if possible.

DNS is working properly as in http call I get logs in ingress-nginx

```
✗  curl http://argocd.staging.project.com 
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but in curl https I don't see any logs inside ingress-nginx pod.

```
curl https://argocd.staging.project.com 
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername argocd.staging.project.com -connect argocd.staging.project.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text
unable to load certificate
139926728525632:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

**cert info**

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in cloudflare-origin.cert 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            0e:e8:98:22:e2:06:be:6d:18:ba:53:49:ef:ac:3a:ae:2b:a8:d3:e1
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority, L = San Francisco, ST = California
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 28 00:48:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Dec 24 00:48:00 2036 GMT
        Subject: O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = CloudFlare Origin CA, CN = CloudFlare Origin Certificate
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c4:6e:4b:53:c7:bb:a3:7a:e4:52:79:39:20:c7:
                    67:1f:67:06:13:ad:8d:cf:48:ae:56:c0:ab:22:e7:
                    5f:22:1b:bb:35:24:74:62:1a:11:5e:be:c3:a7:70:
                    26:54:65:28:e5:bf:4c:d9:de:cc:1a:55:bf:e4:c4:
                    32:93:84:1f:7c:81:01:bb:20:74:72:e0:c9:f4:cc:
                    47:70:76:5e:e7:ce:43:cd:4f:5e:23:7b:b7:66:ac:
                    e6:ce:3a:1d:8f:1c:c1:5e:61:c2:da:64:46:6c:22:
                    00:4d:8a:97:ab:40:93:a8:dd:35:f0:26:43:a4:af:
                    25:5e:2f:27:d5:29:0a:e5:bf:c7:8f:79:8c:3d:07:
                    66:08:23:f9:a8:72:2b:e5:82:d9:90:a3:56:c5:4c:
                    be:a9:2a:12:90:e4:6c:0b:e4:12:45:9f:a9:e9:7c:
                    4b:66:36:3e:ff:f7:2b:a2:49:5d:6d:ef:7e:f4:3e:
                    5c:cf:7f:d2:70:e9:4f:06:c0:ca:ca:5f:ec:22:f7:
                    06:c0:0e:2d:f5:9f:b3:4c:0c:2f:b2:2e:fc:06:6a:
                    de:07:fa:cc:99:fa:83:35:a3:6d:48:13:da:23:2c:
                    52:9c:2f:30:0e:23:cc:af:e8:d1:31:cd:5d:95:bf:
                    cd:ba:43:91:06:c2:b4:b4:bc:ad:c2:e6:01:83:25:
                    d3:41
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                13:86:11:20:22:E5:81:ED:B9:8A:5C:04:0F:3F:03:34:E1:86:55:0C
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:24:E8:53:57:5D:7C:34:40:87:A9:EB:94:DB:BA:E1:16:78:FC:29:A4

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.cloudflare.com/origin_ca

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.staging.project.com, DNS:*.project.com, DNS:project.com
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.cloudflare.com/origin_ca.crl

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         63:fd:c0:b0:ad:95:e4:78:d2:d6:ae:62:8c:5d:a2:a6:c9:12:
         c0:56:02:2a:ba:04:fd:b7:74:d4:0d:ad:5e:55:78:67:63:1a:
         79:83:58:91:b4:a9:77:e1:5e:5d:86:ad:e2:5b:03:a1:88:ff:
         88:bb:f4:29:7d:83:96:89:f8:44:a4:4e:79:c3:ab:14:89:15:
         ea:af:a5:66:f4:6a:fe:2a:a5:55:de:0f:36:a5:cb:95:59:ee:
         3a:51:6b:d3:ca:3c:0a:bc:66:60:ff:77:81:91:57:91:3a:a5:
         ea:05:30:aa:69:01:95:48:44:04:e8:78:a7:bf:03:9b:7e:65:
         f7:5d:91:5d:a9:a2:67:5a:3c:c8:7f:9e:4e:3f:3a:2a:2a:5a:
         68:4b:b5:e2:a1:68:a1:ff:6d:d4:39:9d:00:ab:89:c7:34:aa:
         5b:87:fe:ba:61:c2:94:51:5d:59:c5:a0:0a:dc:0c:23:24:19:
         bc:37:ad:1f:8c:bd:71:89:63:b2:a8:a3:24:20:fc:dd:0f:d9:
         15:b4:a2:b8:8f:7a:c6:a6:50:20:a0:fd:de:1a:79:c6:30:86:
         79:bf:ea:46:e3:1b:e6:86:3b:89:67:d2:c5:bf:d8:62:9f:52:
         6c:d2:1f:b5:f6:03:56:2b:23:5e:30:7a:3e:78:39:f7:cd:a0:
         d0:3c:da:69
```

However for production environment (staging omitted in URL) everything works and handshake is normal.

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername argocd.project.com -connect argocd.project.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text  
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            0e:2d:db:f3:59:21:a2:91:e4:67:79:17:ff:71:8d:e5
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = US, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 15 00:00:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Jun 14 23:59:59 2022 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = sni.cloudflaressl.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:8d:99:4f:55:aa:0c:c2:4d:1b:57:23:e8:73:09:
                    7f:de:d4:ae:50:f8:19:74:0a:23:0f:cc:3e:64:c1:
                    bf:66:56:72:06:4a:c5:0c:13:1f:43:b9:d5:f9:88:
                    e6:f5:4c:4a:02:ee:76:37:9d:ee:e6:26:7d:be:3e:
                    fc:42:a5:97:20
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:A5:CE:37:EA:EB:B0:75:0E:94:67:88:B4:45:FA:D9:24:10:87:96:1F

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                FA:15:4F:CE:7F:3D:C9:27:5A:D3:87:C1:ED:68:A9:FC:CC:BC:E2:84
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.project.com, DNS:sni.cloudflaressl.com, DNS:project.com
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl3.digicert.com/CloudflareIncECCCA-3.crl

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl4.digicert.com/CloudflareIncECCCA-3.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2
                  CPS: http://www.digicert.com/CPS

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.digicert.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cacerts.digicert.com/CloudflareIncECCCA-3.crt

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            CT Precertificate SCTs: 
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 46:A5:55:EB:75:FA:91:20:30:B5:A2:89:69:F4:F3:7D:
                                11:2C:41:74:BE:FD:49:B8:85:AB:F2:FC:70:FE:6D:47
                    Timestamp : Jun 15 16:30:55.567 2021 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:46:02:21:00:DD:C3:A2:FE:62:CE:34:30:BF:41:A3:
                                3D:E3:D3:4B:7A:0C:DD:BF:1E:A0:81:B0:5B:63:0E:A3:
                                83:6B:5D:AF:5C:02:21:00:C7:5C:0F:71:C9:61:11:5A:
                                A8:2F:5F:9A:31:A4:2A:C0:83:B6:2A:29:FC:BD:5D:FA:
                                3C:CF:B5:F6:1E:EE:F0:6B
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 22:45:45:07:59:55:24:56:96:3F:A1:2F:F1:F7:6D:86:
                                E0:23:26:63:AD:C0:4B:7F:5D:C6:83:5C:6E:E2:0F:02
                    Timestamp : Jun 15 16:30:55.564 2021 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:20:25:E2:6B:36:61:E9:F4:EC:28:DE:1D:E3:
                                18:6F:E2:0A:03:EF:29:45:F3:09:0B:27:45:6F:51:78:
                                D5:3A:2A:83:02:21:00:A4:34:A0:B5:D5:FD:F2:42:13:
                                31:93:DF:C4:AD:3E:A7:48:C6:69:C1:9D:04:7A:EA:C7:
                                27:6E:88:69:9B:B9:BF
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 51:A3:B0:F5:FD:01:79:9C:56:6D:B8:37:78:8F:0C:A4:
                                7A:CC:1B:27:CB:F7:9E:88:42:9A:0D:FE:D4:8B:05:E5
                    Timestamp : Jun 15 16:30:55.627 2021 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:21:00:FA:13:20:B1:07:70:46:F4:C2:AD:F0:
                                1C:10:A7:8D:92:23:2C:8A:34:E0:1C:7F:59:8A:CB:7B:
                                C2:CF:07:95:37:02:20:50:78:FA:DF:8D:A4:9C:B9:73:
                                1F:18:ED:51:06:33:8D:B4:F6:CC:0D:8D:46:69:CB:AB:
                                93:17:D2:64:1F:2D:B3
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:46:02:21:00:fc:1b:7b:6f:de:f2:29:5a:11:0c:92:f8:05:
         31:1b:7c:68:f7:6e:e4:0b:5d:15:67:dd:f4:c9:00:d7:77:ad:
         46:02:21:00:a0:98:25:6a:19:3b:ac:51:68:f5:de:9d:cc:93:
         22:b2:ca:18:c8:e9:ec:06:79:77:01:ba:fb:3a:41:3d:2d:cd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok found - it's the limitation of universal cloudflare certificate that doesn't cover subdomains :(

**from their docs**:

#### Only some of your subdomains return SSL errors

Symptom Cloudflare Universal SSL and regular Dedicated SSL certificates only cover the root-level domain (example.com) and one level of subdomains (*.example.com). If visitors to your domain observe errors accessing a second level of subdomains in their browser (such as dev.www.example.com) but not the first level of subdomains (such as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), resolve the issue using one of the following methods below.

#### Resolution

- Ensure the domain is at least on a Business plan and upload a Custom SSL certificate that covers dev.www.example.com, or
- purchase a Dedicated SSL certificate with Custom Hostnames that covers dev.www.example.com, or
- if you have a valid certificate for the second level subdomains at your origin web server, click the orange cloud icon beside the dev.www hostname in the Cloudflare DNS app for example.com.

See here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170566-Troubleshooting-SSL-errors#h_55e4d315-c60d-4798-9c4c-c75d9baed1b7